# Extract data from two pages with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have an agenda as a starting page. This page contains the start times and titles of events and links to the detail page of each event.

My spider extracts all events details (description, location, etc) on the detail page of each single event, except the start time i have to extract on my start page.

How can i extract start time from the start page and other data on each detail pages ?
What is the scrappy way to go ? Using meta['item'] ? i don't get it...
This is my spider for now. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
class LuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "lu"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/agenda"]

def parse(self, response):  
    for href in response.css("div.toggle_container_show > div > a::attr('href')"):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_agenda_contents)

def parse_agenda_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]'):
        item = LuItem()
        item['EventTitle'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]/h1[@id]/text()').extract()
        item['Description'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]//p').extract()
        yield item
```

**Edit:**

I tried to extract start time from the start page using `request.meta['item']` and get a list of **all** the start time in the start page for each event. How to get the start time for **each** event ?
Can someone show me the right direction ?

```
class LuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "lu"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/agenda"]

def parse(self, response):
        item = LuItem()
        item['StartTime'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(., "H")]/span/text()').extract()

        for href in response.css("div.toggle_container_show > div > a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_agenda_contents)
            request.meta['item'] = item         
            yield request

def parse_agenda_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]'):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['EventTitle'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]/h1[@id]/text()').extract()
        item['Description'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]//p').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Edited to use `request.meta['item'] = item`

Comment: Finally found a solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked :

```
class LuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "lu"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/agenda"]

def parse(self, response):
StartTimes = response.xpath('//div[@class="toggle_container_show"]/div/span/text()').extract()
urls =response.xpath('//div[@class="toggle_container_show"]/div/a/@href').extract()

for StartTime,url in zip(StartTimes,urls):
    item = LuItem()
    item['StartTime'] = StartTime
    request = Request(url,callback = self.parse_agenda_contents)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def parse_agenda_contents(self, response):
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]'):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['EventTitle'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]/h1[@id]/text()').extract()
    item['Description'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]//p').extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: Exactly the same as in the official doc, right? Great! ;)

Comment: @ narko Yep ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Using meta would do it in your case. Please see the official documentation here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
  item = MyItem()
  item['main_url'] = response.url
  request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                         callback=self.parse_page2)
  request.meta['item'] = item
  return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
  item = response.meta['item']
  item['other_url'] = response.url
  return item
```

Comment: Wouldn't the following be more direct in parse_page1()?
`request.meta = item`
Followed by this in parse_page2()
`item = response.meta`

Comment: If you only want to send the item information then I guess yes, but if you had more stuff to share in the callback, that wouldn't work.